# how can you retrieve source code in python, inspect gives type error

Tags: python, numpy, source-code-protection

In order to get better at programming, analysing numpy and scipy's source code could come in handy.

```
import inspect,numpy as np

x = [1,2]
inspect.getsource(np.max(x))

gives TypeError
```

please help,kind regards

Comment: Your error message tells you `TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got int64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `numpy` and `scipy` code, check the official documentation.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html

Often these have a [[source]](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2589-L2706) link. Or it running `ipython`, just using `np.max??` gives the same thing.

In this case, most of the display is the docs, and the actual code is short:

```
def amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue, initial=np._NoValue,
         where=np._NoValue):
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
                          keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
File:      /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py
```

This tells us that `np.max` (or `amax`) delegates the action to a similarly name `max` method.  And if we dig further we see that the method is `built-in`, that is, it is compiled code that we cannot readily read.  This is a rather common situation in `numpy`.  Functions delegate to similarly named methods. Unless you are prepared to do some serious reading of `c` code, this is as far as you'll get.  And as far as you need to go, unless you want to be `numpy` developer/contributor.

Answer (score 1):

`np.max(x)` is an integer, `2`.  An integer has no source code.

Try simply

```
inspect.getsource (np.max)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the python documentation

> inspect.getsource(object)

> Return the text of the source code for an object. The argument may be a module, >class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object. The source code is >returned as a single string. An OSError is raised if the source code cannot be >retrieved.

It appears in your example that you are calling the function.
Try just `inspect.getsource(np.max)`